# What are the screen editor commands for MIT LOGO for the Apple II?

Tags: apple-ii, logo-language

I'm playing with [MIT LOGO for the Apple II (1981)](https://archive.org/details/MIT_LOGO_for_the_Apple_II_1981). When I
type `TO GREET :NAME` and hit ENTER it drops me into the "MIT LOGO
screen editor." What are the commands I can use here to edit, save,
etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This disk image is probably built from
[`files/aplogo/logo.299`](https://github.com/PDP-10/its-vault/blob/master/files/aplogo/logo.299) in the
[`PDP-10/its-vault`](https://github.com/PDP-10/its-vault) repo on GitHub.com, or very similar
source. That same directory has a documentation file,
[`usage.doc`](https://github.com/PDP-10/its-vault/blob/master/files/aplogo/usage.doc), but unfortunately that doesn't seem to
document the screen editor commands. (It also seems to document a
number of things not in that particular version of LOGO.)

The commands are dispatched from a table called [`EDSTBL`](https://github.com/PDP-10/its-vault/blob/master/files/aplogo/logo.299#L8081-L8140),
which contains the ASCII character to match followed by the routine to
which to jump. They are as follows:

- `^A`: Go to beginning of line
- `^B`: Go back one screen
- `^C`: Complete edit (save and exit)
- `^D`: Delete char under cursor
- `^E`: Go to end of line
- `^F`: Go to next screen
- `^G`: Quit without saving
- `←`, `^H`: Move back one character
- `^K`: Delete to end of line ("Kill")
- `^L`: Center current line on screen
- `^M`: Insert newline
- `^N`: Move down to next (logical) line
- `^O`: Insert a newline, leaving the cursor at the end of the
  existing line ("Open")
- `^P`: Move up to previous (logical) line
- `→`, `^U`:  Move forward one character
- `ESC`, `^[`: Delete previous character

Lines longer than 40 characters will be wrapped, with an exclamation
point `!` displayed at in column 40 of the screen for all screen lines
but the last that are part of the logical line.

The `RETRIEVE` command from `usage.doc`, to re-enter a screen editor
session abandoned with `^G`, doesn't seem to exist in this version of
LOGO, but `EDIT` (or `ED`) with no argument does the same thing.

Comment: Here's when we first encountered a 1980 version of APLOGO: https://github.com/PDP-10/its/pull/934
A list of edit commands appears near the end.

Comment: You are right about the source of the archive.org copy.  Here's when we brought that to life: https://github.com/PDP-10/its/pull/1386